# Close open views on closing e4 application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I had an e3 rcp app. When I close it and reopen it all opened views are closed.
After updating app to e4 and after close than open app the views are still opened.
Any idea how to close these views?

Iv tried to implement something like this but its not working

`

```
public void closeActiveViews() {
        try {
            IWorkbenchPage activePage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
            if (activePage != null) {
                IViewReference[] views = activePage.getViewReferences();
                if (views != null) {
                    for (IViewReference view : views) {
                        activePage.hideView(view.getView(false));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error("Could not hide views ", exception);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: e4 doesn't use those classes - do you really mean a pure e4 application which doesn't use any `org.eclipse.ui` plug-ins? In fact e4 doesn't even have views, just parts. If you are using the above classes you are using Eclipse 4 with the 3.x compatibility plug-ins.

Comment: Actually yes. But Im wondering why it is not working now with e4. It is working with e3

Comment: Yes what? You are using 3.x compatibility mode? The code looks reasonable for compatabilty mode - have you debugged it to see what part is not working?